# WPF Design time support for list with custom objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, design-time

I am making a user control that is a listview with button in it. 
the buttons have an text and an image.

the listview is bound to an observablecollection of MyType. Adding items to the list and so on works fine and is visible when i run the application. But i also want to have design time support for these properties.

What am i doing wrong? thanks for your help.

**usercontrol.xaml**

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="client:MyItem">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ButtonText}" />
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}"></Image>
                                </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

**usercontrol.cs**

```
 public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

    }

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();


    [Description("Items in sidebar")]
    [Category("Data")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}
```

**MyItem.cs**

```
[Serializable()]
public  class MyItem 
{

   public string ButtonText { get; set; }
   public ImageSource Imagepath { get; set; }

}
```

**Usage of the user control**

```
 <my:UserControl1>
                <my:UserControl1.Items>
                    <my:MyItem ButtonText="test" Imagepath="../img.png" />
                    <my:MyItem ButtonText="test2" Imagepath="../img2.png" />
                </my:UserControl1.Items>
            </my:UserControl1>
```

Comment: I also have little luck with this. In fact, while you stuck in listview, i'm stuck with treeview But perhaps googling d:designdata could help a little

Comment: d:designdata is for setting up sample data i guess. i've been inspecting the microsoft dll's with dotpeek, and things look the same as i have right now. but i can't find why it's not working

Comment: How do you provide the design time Items?

Comment: Have you set the DataContext of your UserControl to 'this'?

Comment: @GlenThomas Yes i have, i added the code to my question

Comment: @Onur I add the items using the properties window of my user control when it's added to my main window. this generates xaml to provide the items. i just added an example to the bottom of my question

Comment: Btw. There's a mismatch between `ImagePath` and `Imagepath` (in code and XAML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me (images are not present but that shouldn't matter):

[image: Preview]

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace UnrelatedTests
{
    [Serializable()]
    public  class MyItem 
    {

       public string ButtonText { get; set; }
       public ImageSource Imagepath { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
        private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();


        [Description("Items in sidebar")]
        [Category("Data")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UnrelatedTests.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:unrelatedTests="clr-namespace:UnrelatedTests"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="unrelatedTests:MyItem">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ButtonText}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Imagepath}"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="UnrelatedTests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:UnrelatedTests"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <my:UserControl1>
            <my:UserControl1.Items>
                <my:MyItem ButtonText="test" Imagepath="../img.png" />
                <my:MyItem ButtonText="test2" Imagepath="../img2.png" />
            </my:UserControl1.Items>
        </my:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update:**

If you make the `MyItem` a `struct` instead of a class, the design time preview is almost live.

Comment: Does it work in design time as well? With design time, i mean that when you change the value it also changes immediatly in the designer without building? Did you make changes to my code to get it working?

Comment: I only adjusted the "ImagePath" and "Imagepath" to be the same. There is no "live" preview during design time. Closing the `MainWindow.xaml` and reopening will refresh as well as a (probably faster) recompile.

Comment: The live preview is what i want to achieve. just like in other third party control libraries.

Comment: Have you tried to decompile one of these? I just tried to get "live" design time preview by using the user control code right inside the main window (i.e. ListView with datatemplate and supplied items) and it doesn't work either.

Comment: @jonasvermeulen See my update at the end of the post.

Comment: That is exactly what i need ! With a struct it works indeed. i don't know why, but is works :-) . i will accept your answer as correct. Big thanks for your help !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84576/discussion-between-onur-and-jonas-vermeulen).

Comment: Can u please kill that mouse cursor on the image? i thought it was dust or some insect on my monitor, and tried to wipe it just until i realized it was unwipeable and scroll my screen down.

Answer (score 0):

When I want design time visibility of item templates, I create controls with hard-coded items like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Grid>
            <Button/>
        </Grid>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

And then simply refactor the hard-coded item content into a template:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Button/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Easy.